# Solaris DSCC delete offline directory server

Tags: ldap, solaris

I have made a copy of one of our live ldap servers to use in testing environment.

In our live system we have 2 ldap servers in master/master configuration.

My question is on our testing environment as there is only one server how can I delete the offline ldap server from DSCC. I have tried to remove it using the web interface but as its offline it throws an can't communicate error.

I have also tried using the `dsccreg remove-server` command with no success.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look at MOS note 1920317.1